# SQL: Turn an IN to an AND instead of OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Code in question:

```
...and crset.Name IN (Select [part] from [dbo].[SplitString](@Type, ',')...
```

Assume `@Type` is `'Blue,White'` and the splitstring function allows me to turn that string into a list for using IN.

Currently this returns all entries that have blue or white, let's say house color. What I want is a way to say "Only those houses whose colors are in the list and must have ALL of the colors in the list. This would mean that there are multiple entries for each house: one entry for each color that it has (which is the case in the db). That means that houses that have entries for "Red" and "White" would not show up, entries for only "Blue" would not show up, entries for "white" would not show up but any house which has multiple records (blue, white) would.

Let me know if you need more code to work from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by using a CTE:

```
with vals as (
      Select part from [dbo].[SplitString](@Type, ',')
     )
select t.house
from table t
where t.color in (select part from vals)
group by t.house
having count(distinct t.color) = (select distinct part from vals);
```

If you want to limit the matches to the *exact* colors, then remove the `where` clause.

Comment: Would an inner join be faster than the `in` clause?

Comment: Having one little hitch with this. "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Or if I put it where I really think it should be:

An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Is more coded needed?

Comment: @MetalPhoenix . . . You need to rewrite the entire query to follow this approach.  You cannot just filter in the `where` clause to do what you want, because it affects multiple rows.

Comment: I was hoping that that wasn't what that error meant. Rewriting the entire query isn't out of the question but it is beyond my ability atm. I'm going to mark yours as the answer because I can read SQL well enough to see what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
select house
from crset
where crset.Name IN (Select [part] from [dbo].[SplitString](@Type, ','))
group by house
having count(distinct crset.Name) = (Select count([part]) from [dbo].[SplitString](@Type, ','))
```

You can group by the `house` and count if there are as many colors for them as in your list you provide. If so, then all the colors you filter in the `where` condition where also in the list.

Comment: Thanks. I can see where that's going and I see how that just might be the ticket but I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near 'Select' (right after the equals sign) (even when I put it in a new query). One more nudge?

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to put the select into parentheses.

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by explaining your SQL at a high level.